# Log complete HTTP HEAD in WSO2 ESB API

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have several API resources deployed in the WSO2 ESB. In order to monitor the calls they receive Web services exposed in API resources, I would like to show in the log full HTTP header of the request.

I know I can do this parameter by parameter from the HTTP header, but I wonder if there is any way to do this in a unique way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open /repository/conf/log4j.properties and uncomment the following line.

```
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=DEBUG
```

Comment: Thanks. But, is it not possible to do this in definition of the API resource? I mean, just in one line, not to access parameter by parameter.

Comment: It's not possible to do this in the definition it self. To access the headers in the definition you will have to access one header  by one.